# LinkManager Adds /sitecore/content into the URL

Tags: links, link-manager

I am dynamically constructing the left menu for the product

View:

```
            @foreach (var item in Model.Children)
       {
         <div class="btn btn-default">

        <a id="lnk-@item.DisplayName"  href="@Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(@item)"><span class="@item["Icon"]"></span><span class="nameText">@item["Title"]</span></a>


              </div>
         }
```

when clicking the link am getting url as 
QAV1/sitecore/Content/Property/Ridgepoint/Photos?sc_lang=en

how to avoid sitecore/content/ in the url?

Site Definition:

```
           <site name="qav1" patch:before="site[@name='website']"
         virtualFolder="/"
        physicalFolder="/"
        rootPath="/sitecore/content/Property/"
        startItem="/Home"
        database="web"
        domain="extranet"
        allowDebug="false"
        cacheHtml="true"
        htmlCacheSize="50MB"
        enablePreview="true"
        enableWebEdit="true"
        enableDebugger="true"
        useDisplayName="true"

        disableClientData="false"/>
</sites>
```

Comment: What's the configuration for the site in question? my guess is that the site definition is not correct. Also what is the full URL that gets rendered, is it just "qav1/sitecore/content/Product/MenuName"

Comment: Full URL:QAV1/sitecore/Content/Property/Ridgepoint/Photos?sc_lang=en

Comment: added site definition

Comment: Can you also add here definition of your linkmanager? Something like this - <linkManager defaultProvider="sitecore">
<providers>
<clear />
<add name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" addAspxExtension="false" alwaysIncludeServerUrl="true" encodeNames="true" languageEmbedding="never" languageLocation="filePath" shortenUrls="true" useDisplayName="false" />
</providers>
</linkManager>

Comment: Are you sure that you are in context of qav1 site? Can you put this "@Sitecore.Context.GetSiteName()" before the link just to see whether this is correct. Maybe LinkManager is using default "website" site definition and that's why you have full path

Comment: Also try to remove "/" at the end in rootpath in your site definition and make it like this rootPath="/sitecore/content/Property". We had some trouble with this in Sitecore 7 could be you are facing something similar as rootPath is ending with "/" and also startItem starts with "/" so you have double "//" at the end when these are combined

Comment: Another thing I just realized that you have startItem set as "/Home". Do you have item like that in your tree? If no, then remove "Home" and make it just "/". Links are always generated relatively to startItem and if it doesn't exist, I believe you end with full path which is your case...

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting the full path is because your Site definition points to:

/sitecore/content/Property/

But the item you're rendering a url for is:

qav1/sitecore/content/Product/MenuName

This means, it's not under the Property item which is the starting point of the site. So, for the url to work (i.e. Sitecore to be able to find the item based on the url) it needs the full item path (as it wouldn't find it under Property). So the MenuName or the Product item needs to be under Property, in that case it will render the url without gav1/sitecore/content.

Comment: my url is QAV1/sitecore/Content/Property/Ridgepoint/Photos?sc_lang=en added in the previous comment

Comment: Your rootpath is pointing to /sitecore/content/Property, so there's no URL possible to render without the full path for the Product since it lives in /sitecore/content/Property